# Django oembed URLs for embedded tweets

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a list of a few hundred Twitter oembed URLs but I don't know how to implement the GET requests of a list of ids in a view.

Edited - OP was using URLS, not ids.

```
<div class="tweets">
    {% for id in ids %}
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(".tweets").append(<div id="tweet" tweetID={{ id }}>)
    </script>

<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<script>

window.onload = (function(){

var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");

twttr.widgets.createTweet(
  id, tweet,
  {
    conversation : 'none',    // or all
    cards        : 'hidden',  // or visible
    linkColor    : '#cc5443', // default is blue
    theme        : 'light'    // or dark
  })
.then (function (el) {
  el.contentDocument.querySelector(".footer").style.display = "none";
});

});

</script>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I'm trying to loop through a list of tweet ids and embed them. How do I make the JQuery loop through to create a div for each list item?

Comment: can you be more specific and also add an example?

Comment: Looks like Rapydscript might get me going

Comment: https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript

Comment: https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RapydML](https://bitbucket.org/pyjeon/rapydml) and [Rapydscript](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript#leveraging-other-apis)
are what I was looking for. First, I created a nodeenv env. Now, I'm rewriting the above code in pythonic javascript and pythonic html.